# How to Count total rows on a shipment

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm trying to count the total number of lines on each shipment:

```
SELECT  Shipments.ShipmentId, 
        SalesOrders.SalesOrderId as OrderNumber,  
        Count(SalesOrderItems.SalesOrderItem) as NumberOfLines

FROM SalesOrders 

INNER JOIN SalesOrderItems on SalesOrders.SalesOrder = SalesOrderItems.SalesOrder 
INNER JOIN Shipments on SalesOrderItems.SalesOrder = Shipments.SalesOrder

GROUP BY SalesOrderItems.SalesOrderItem, SalesOrders.SalesOrderId, Shipments.ShipmentId

ORDER BY Shipments.ShipmentID ASC
```

Currently I'm getting:

```
ShipmentID  | OrderNumber    | NumberOfLines
SH00000001  | SO-0000001     | 1
SH00000001  | SO-0000001     | 1
SH00000002  | SO-0000007     | 1
SH00000003  | SO-0000006     | 1
SH00000003  | SO-0000006     | 1
```

And I should be getting:

```
ShipmentID  | OrderNumber    | NumberOfLines
SH00000001  | SO-0000001     | 1
SH00000001  | SO-0000001     | 2
SH00000002  | SO-0000007     | 1
SH00000003  | SO-0000006     | 1
SH00000003  | SO-0000006     | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` clause should match the *unaggregated* columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT s.ShipmentId, 
       so.SalesOrderId as OrderNumber,  
       Count(soi.SalesOrderItem) as NumberOfLines
FROM SalesOrders so INNER JOIN
     SalesOrderItems soi
     ON so.SalesOrder = soi.SalesOrder INNER JOIN
     Shipments s
     ON soi.SalesOrder = s.SalesOrder
GROUP BY soi.SalesOrderId, s.ShipmentId
ORDER BY s.ShipmentID ASC;
```

Note that I've added table aliases.  These make the queries easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `SalesOrderItems.SalesOrderItem` from your `group by` clause, you don't want it (as can be deduced from it not existing on your sample result dataset).